# Process ReactiveCollection CollectionChangeEvent in batches asynchronously

Tags: reactiveui

I am exploring Reactive UI. I have an ObservableCollection of models in which objects are added at a very high speed. I handle the collectionchanged event and add viewModels for each model in another ObservableCollection. 
  Can we suppress the CollectionChanged event for Model list and raise an event for a bunch of records or after a specified time interval has lapsed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here's how to do it:

```
using (someReactiveCollection.SuppressChangeNotifications()) {
    // TODO: Add a bunch of items
}
```